# What are good books on the Panov-Botvinnik Attack and playing with an IQP?

Tags: opening, books, caro-kann, recommendations, isolated-pawn

Respectively, what are good books for the Panov-Botvinnik Attack and playing with an isolated queen pawn?

Comment: I like the Lorin d'Costa book I linked to your last question, and it has a strong focus on IQP positions. That's certainly what I learnt the Panov from. But whether it is best, well that's opinion, don't be surprised if this gets closed for that reason.

Comment: Adding on to @IanBush comment.  It is common on StackExchange to not allow opinion, but this community is stricter in that regard than other communities I belong to.  For example, you may just ask for two books, or maybe books you would recommended.  "Best Books" is definitely opinion.  Also, it is good practice to ask only one question.  I answered only the IQP question.

Answer (score 5):

For Isolated Queen Pawn play I would pick up a pawn structure book.  They typically start off with IQP.  Most of the game examples will be Queen's Gambit, but the beauty of a pawn structure approach is that it applies independent of opening. It's worth studying pawn structures generally once you are not dropping pieces regularly as strategy becomes more important.

Two best books in English (Opinion)

- Pawn Structure Chess - Andrew Soltis
- Chess Structures A grandmasters guide - Mauricio Flores Rios

Answer (score 1):

Ivan Sokolov's book, Winning Chess Middlegames, is all about pawn structures. He devotes one 94-page long chapter to playing with and against an isolated queen's pawn and then another 42-page long chapter to hanging pawns, which is what isolated queen's pawn positions often turn into. It's an excellent and instructive book.